# Trying to connect to my github repo using vscode running a virtual environment but it loads every single library?

Tags: python, github, visual-studio-code

I am starting to use github and have managed to create an account and link and authorise it to vscode.

Everything runs fine until i select a virtual environment and add it to my workspace.

I immediately then get 1000+ changes and it looks like every single item in my lib/python3.7 folder is being tracked as part of git.

Surely this can't be right?

Does github not work with virtual environments in python in vscode?

Thanks

Comment: You could try making a `.gitignore` file in your repository.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `gitignore` - Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore.

create a `.gitignore` file in your repository and add the `folders/files` you want to ignore in that file.

read more about `.gitignore` here https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

if you have committed your files already, after creating `.gitignore` file use this command to remove cache:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

then `add` and `commit` as usual

Comment: Thank you for this it works. It seems strange that it includes everything in my virtual environment but looking deeper in my terminal the hidden .git file is in the root folder which includes all the bin and lib files.

Comment: that's great. If this answer helped you, mark it as correct answer else your question will be labelled as unanswered.